# unknown override specifier and missing type specifier - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been getting a strange error in Visual Studio 2017. The error is

> Error C3646   'collisionSys': unknown override specifier
>      
>  Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>       support default-int

The strange thing about it is that when I build the solution, I get this error but when I delete the declaration of `collisionSys` and build, then re-declare `collisionSys` and build again, it succeeds. Though it happens again when I make some changes in `CollisionSystem.hpp`

 My code is as follows:

#### CollisionSystem.hpp

```
 #ifndef COLLISION_SYSTEM__HPP
    #define COLLISION_SYSTEM__HPP

    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include "../EntityManager.hpp"
    #include "../Entity.hpp"
    #include "../Components/Display.hpp"
    #include "../Components/Flags.hpp"
    #include "../Components/Movement.hpp"
    #include <Level.hpp>

    class Level;

    class CollisionSystem
    {
    public:
        CollisionSystem();
        void run(Level&, CameraSystem*, EntityManager*);
    private:
        static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> m_Ents;
    };
#endif
```

#### CollisionSystem.cpp

```
#include <Systems/CollisionSystem.hpp>

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> CollisionSystem::m_Ents;

CollisionSystem::CollisionSystem()
{

}

void CollisionSystem::run(Level& level, CameraSystem* cameraSys, 
EntityManager* EntMan)
{
    // Some collision detection here
}
```

#### LocalWorld.hpp

```
#ifndef LOCAL_WORLD__HPP
#define LOCAL_WORLD__HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <conio.h>
#include "GameState.hpp"
#include "StateMgr.hpp"
#include "Game.hpp" 
#include "TileMap.hpp"
#include "Level.hpp"
#include "ECS/Entity.hpp"
#include "ECS/Components/IncludeAllComponents.hpp"
#include "ECS/ResourceManager.hpp"
#include "ECS/EntityManager.hpp"
#include "ECS/Systems/IncludeAllSystems.hpp"

// Map Names
enum class MapName
{
    Map1
};

// Forward declaration
class Level;

class LocalWorld : public GameState
{
public:
    LocalWorld();
    ~LocalWorld();

    virtual void Pause();
    virtual void Resume();

    virtual void HandleEvents(sf::Event& eType);
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw();
private:
    std::map<MapName, Level*> Maps;
    Level* activeLevel;

    ResourceManager ResMan;
    EntityManager EntMan;

    CameraSystem cameraSys;
    MovementSystem movementSys;
    ControlSystem controlSys;
    RenderSystem renderSys;
    CollisionSystem collisionSys;
};

#endif
```

The error is on line `CollisionSystem collisionSys;` in `LocalWorld.hpp`

#### IncludeAllSystems.hpp

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_ALL_SYSTEMS__HPP
#define INCLUDE_ALL_SYSTEMS__HPP

#include "CameraSystem.hpp"
#include "ControlSystem.hpp"
#include "MovementSystem.hpp"
#include "RenderSystem.hpp"
#include "CollisionSystem.hpp"

#endif
```

Here, this file includes all the Systems with `CollisionSystem.hpp`
I looked at other questions with the same error but still can't fix it.

### EDIT:

The error is fixed by moving `#include <Level.hpp>` from `CollisionSystem.hpp` to `CollisionSystem.cpp`. Can anyone explain why is that so?

Comment: on what lines are the errors? did you enable c++11? I dont see any `override` btw

Comment: Seems you might use more forward declaration... Maybe a circular dependency ?

Comment: @tobi303 The error is on line CollisionSystem collisionSys; in LocalWorld.hpp

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried declaring CollisionSystem in LocalWorld.hpp but it says undefined class

Comment: *"CollisionSystem.hpp"* only need `<vector>` and `<memory>` as includes.

Comment: @Jarod42 for simplicity, I didn't post the code in the run function of CollisionSystem, so other headers are used in this function

Comment: @Ashar7: all those headers should go in cpp not in header. That's my point.

Comment: Precompiled headers issue?

Comment: @tobi303 that's MSVC's way of barfing when it encounters an undeclared identifier. Well, one of them anyway.

Comment: @Ripi2 What does that mean? I'm just a beginner to VS

Comment: Using PH is a technique to avoid compiling the same header time and time. No changes in the header,  no recompilation. But sometimes, changes in your code (about including some header) make the compiler to mess up. The solution is to delete the precompiled headers and re-compile the whole project again.

Comment: @Ripi2 I added CollisionSystem.hpp in include ditectories, does that treat it as a PH?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15823048/3871028

Comment: @Ripi2 Well, I don't need PH as I'm always editing those files.

Comment: @Ripi2 I created a new project and put everything there, but still the error isn't solved

Comment: Does `GameState` class has a member called `collisionSys`? If so, you are trying to redefine it without being virtual.

Comment: @Ripi2 No, it doesn't.

Comment: Oh and the error is fixed now by moving `#include <Level.hpp>` to `CollisionSystem.cpp` from `CollisionSystem.hpp`. Thanks to @Jarod42